# Windows 10 docker update constantly updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, docker

Everytime I restart, I'm getting an Update Wizard from Docker with the title `A new version of Docker is available!` from version 1.12.0-stable(build: 5968) to 1.12.1(build:7135). The dialog started with:

> **Important**
>
> The auto update function will unfortunately not be able to
>   install this update. To upgrade, please install the 1.12.1 release
>   manually by downloading the installer from:

I do the update and after restart I get the wizard again.

Is this an known problem? I haven't found anything on the Internet.

In advance thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running the installer as an administrator?

Comment: no, I will try. But the wizard pup up by itself. So I don't know how to start by my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the installation image from this [link](https://download.docker.com/win/stable/InstallDocker.msi) and run it manually to update docker. The section including the download link is on the update popup as follows:

> ## Important
>
> The auto update function will unfortunately not be able to install this update. To upgrade, please install the 1.12.1 release manually by downloading the installer from:
>
> https://download.docker.com/win/stable/InstallDocker.msi